# Two ways of initializing `rand()`

Tags: c++, static-cast, srand

Most of the time I see an initialization of the C pseudo-random number generator, it reads as follows:

```
 srand(time(NULL));
```

Anyway I saw C++ codes using

```
srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
```

Are the two lines equivalent as a matter of goodness of the initialisation or there is a reason to prefer the more verbose way in C++?

Comment: Not an answer to your question but [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) should be preferred in C++ (11 or later).

Comment: Well, even better, prefer `#include <random>`

Comment: This is just a matter of style. If you don't write the explicit cast, it will do the same conversion implicitly.

Comment: You should watch this: [rand() Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact type of [`std::time_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time_t) is unspecified. It is *usually* a signed integer. [`std::srand`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand) takes an `unsigned` (i.e. `unsigned int`) argument.

There is therefore a mismatch between the type returned by [`std::time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time) and what `std::srand` expects. Depending on the exact type of `std::time_t` the compiler might silently convert it, but it might not.

For example on Windows using the Visual C++ compiler [`time`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f4c8f33.aspx) returns a *64-bit* integer. This can't readily be converted to `unsigned int` without loss of precision, which the compiler might (should? I don't remember) warn about.

Therefore the cast, to make sure the correct type is passed to `std::srand`.

---

As the difference in the argument passed to `time`, in C++ `0` has since before standardization been implicitly convertible to a null pointer. IIRC modern C (since C99?) does it as well, but it haven't always been the case. Therefore the symbolic constant `NULL` for null pointers in C, and the integer constant `0` in C++.

Note that since C++11 the recommended null pointer is [`nullptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr).

Comment: I remember that one of these codes was written by a windows user, now it makes sense!